# Oracle DB - add "or" condition in MERGE INTO

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query:

```
MERGE INTO MY_TABLE dest
  USING( SELECT '2018' as YEAR, '012345678' as ID, 'r' as BMR FROM dual ) src
    ON( dest.YEAR = src.YEAR and dest.ID = src.ID and dest.BMR = src.BMR )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET LIB = 'Hello, world'
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT( YEAR, ID, BMR, LIB ) 
 VALUES( src.YEAR, src.ID, src.BMR, 'Hello, world' );
```

It permits me to update value if the row exists, if not an insert is done.
Right now, I run this query 2 times with BMR = 'r', then with BMR = 'm'.

What I want is something like `'r' or 'm' as BMR` in my second line. What is the right way to do that?

Comment: what about using union all in your second line and adding the similar query for 'm' BMR ?

Comment: So easy! Thank you @MaximBorunov. You can add as an answer and I will accept it.